# Is "dictator" a negative word?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Recently, I was discussing something about open source software in the [FOSS stack exchange](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/2458/4160) and to explain a certain technical concept (*permissive licenses*), I made the analogy of *dictatorship vs democracy*.

Now, I don't know whether the word dictator itself is negative or it is the bad ruler who brings it a bad name, but people seem to be taking this word quite negatively. In fact, the *WordNet* dictionary defines the word as:

```
  n 1: a speaker who dictates to a secretary or a recording
       machine

  2: a ruler who is unconstrained by law [syn: {dictator},
     {potentate}]
```

I don't see any negative connotation there. In fact, in our software world, there is the concept of a [benevolent dictator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) which implies that dictatorship can be actually very good.

Comment: The original Latin root for the term was not (originally) negative -- it was just an alternate term for, eg, "emperor".  But human nature is such that there are few truly "benevolent" dictators, and even those that are are often not regarded that way by large segments of the population.  "Power corrupts, and absolute power corrupts absolutely."

Comment: I'd say that the definitions are listed in the wrong order (in a dictionary that lists senses by frequency of usage, as most do). // '[Is] the word _dictator_ itself negative, or it is the bad ruler who brings it a bad name?' wrongly implies that words are absolutes, having no connection with how people perceive them. 'Dictator' certainly has negative connotations, and very possibly denotation.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This is not from any hard-cover dictionary, but the `dictd` linux command. Maybe their `WordNet` ordering isn't updated to account for this yet.

Comment: It's much more cultural/political than linguistic.  Most western societies have been conditioned to see democracy (verging on populism) as the highest form of government.  Thus, since a dictator is the antithesis of democracy, the word must automatically be negative.

Comment: "Your Holiness" is the proper way to address the pope. But I can still use it to ridicule or insult you because I overstate it. Calling a head of state a dictator can still be insulting even when dictators aren't inherently evil (only unstoppably evil _if they are an evil person_)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most definitions in   dictionaries   carry negative connotations. The fact that you have to add "benevolent" implies that it is not by definition. *Benevolent dictator* is actually an oxymoron.

***[Dictator](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/dictator)***:

> - a ruler who has complete power over a country, ***especially one who has gained it using military force***.
> - ***a person who behaves as if they have complete power over other people***, and tells them what to do.

(OLD)

***[Dictator](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/dictator)***

> - A dictator is someone who has absolute power — or who at least behaves as if they do by bossing others around.
> - In government, a dictator is a ruler who has total control over a country, with no checks or balances to prevent abuse of power. Dictator can also describe someone who acts like that on a smaller scale. When your sister is getting married and your mom makes her order roses instead lilies for the table arrangements and yells at you for addressing the invitations too slowly and insists that all of her coworkers be invited, she’s acting like a dictator.

(vocabulary.com)

Comment: True. However, even in both the definitions you have specified,  I don't see any *inherent* negativity about dictatorship. For example, if you substitute it for *King* or *Emperor*, both your definitions will still apply to them and be valid, and yet *King* and *Emperor* aren't negative words, are they?

Comment: Kings and Emperors refers to dinasties, and not all of them had to fight or kill (think about Queen Elizabeth II  or the Japanese Emperor) : Dictator has a specific 'negative' connotation in that respect. I don't see how it can be neutral or positive.

Comment: *"...and not all of them had to fight or kill"* - In fact, a lot of them did. If you read about the Roman History, a lot of it is [written in blood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caligula). Same is the case with Greek, Indian, Persian, etc. Killing people and occupying territories was almost like a pastime in the old times. I think, the negativity surrounding *dictator* is due to the act of two specific dictators of modern times: Hitler and Mussolini.

Comment: Yes, that may well be, but whatever the reason, the term has aquired and still has a negative connotation. If you describe your boss as a dictator, I really doubt he/she would take it as a neutral compliment. Please check with other reliable dictionaries you can easily find online.

Comment: @PrahladYeri There is a difference between an emperor or king and a dictator. Cincinnatus, Louis XIV or Peter the Great, or even the Pope or King Mswati were/are powerful absolute monarchs, but no one would classify them as *dictators*, as their autocracy was/is constrained by competing institutions (e.g. the nobility, the clergy, the military), traditions, social norms, economic limitations, and so on. Prior to industrialization and mass communication, it was almost impossible to be a *dictator* in the modern sense of wielding power without competition as a source of authority.

Comment: @choster Indeed, all that is true. However, its not just a possibility of dictatorship in modern times, but because a few dictators actually did wrongful things, the word has attained the negative meaning. Having said that, a dictatorship can also be a good thing (like [BDFL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life)), but since this word is already a negative, we don't have any other words left in English to describe such a situation, do we?

Comment: @PrahladYeri - I wonder if your question is about usage or if it has an 'ideological' nuance also.

Comment: @PrahladYeri Actually, I made an error while revising my comment— Cincinnatus was revered precisely because he was content to be a dictator (i.e. the constitutional officer of that name) and not a monarch. I would say in the modern era, any deviation from democratic forms, whether constitutionally as in Brunei or unconstitutionally as in the C.A.R., is greeted skeptically. In other words, by definition, it is not a "good thing" by any name. Praising any aspect of even a "good" dictatorship can be highly contentious— ask any Chilean about Augusto Pinochet or South Korean about Park Chung-Hee.

Comment: @choster "Praising any aspect of even a "good" dictatorship can be highly contentious" In the open source software world, there is a highly used word called *benevolent dictator*. A project can in fact be under benevolent dictatorship and all project members are OK with it. Most notable example of benevolent dictator is Linus Torvalds, the inventor of Linux.

Comment: @Josh61 Yes, I basically also want to understand the big divide between the negative aspect of the word dictator, and the positive meaning of the word [benevolent dictator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life) in the open source software world. Indeed, if the word dictator is so negative, why is Linus Torvalds (inventor of Linux) called a dictator!

Comment: @PrahladYeri - it is called 'semantic change', when the meaning and  the connotation of terms change over time. The reason why  a system is called dictator or any other noum is a question of personal choice of the inventor. But why did he use the the adjective "benevolent" in front of it?

Comment: @Josh61 Torvalds didn't choose the adjective, rather the community [awarded him](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benevolent_dictator_for_life#Persons_sometimes_referred_to_as_.22Benevolent_dictators_for_life.22) that title. Originally, the term was coined by Eric Raymond in his book *Cathedral and the Bazaar*. But I think the practical reason for its use is that there is no other word to describe what a leader of a FOSS project does other than Benevolent Dictator.

Answer (score 0):

"Dictator" is not merely negative as it describes a particular type of power.
In the Roman empire the dictatorship was not badly rated as it could with certain leader like : Nero ; or in other country other time Hitler.
The dictatorship is the power of one person on people ; this power could be good or not. For Montesquieu or Th. More the reference to the dictator was rather positive. But nowadays, since the XXth. century, dictator has a negative sense

Comment: I think you are forgetting the evil Roman emperor [Caligula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caligula)

Comment: Among others ... You (are) 2000000% right ! :)